# Uexpected token 'tag' jade node.js

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I get:

```
    Unexpected token 'tag' expected 'text', 'code', ':', 'newline' or 'eos'
```

because of this code:

```
        label(for="polaziste")Polaziste
```

in

```
#main
    form(action="/raspored" method=post)
        label(for="polaziste")Polaziste
        input(type="list" id="polaziste")
        datalist#polaziste
            for pol,i in popis
                option(value = pol)
```

Why? :)

Comment: Also, add a comma after `type="list"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
label(for="polaziste") Polaziste
```

Notice space before Polaziste.

Comment: :) thanks. Is it a general rule in jade when writing something between the tags?

Comment: Well, templates are like that, while being very useful, they require you to adhere to some rules - otherwise it would be difficult to interpret what we are asking it to do.

Comment: btw, what does polaziste mean?

Comment: It means "starting point" in croatian. In this case it means "a place from where the train leaves". Its actually "polazište" but I kinda got used to leaving out all the nonstandard characters from our alphabet while coding

Comment: Keep your non-standard characters there, there are languages where it is impossible to write without them, like the spanish ñ or the french ç, and the user will feel uncomfortable if they're not there. New character encodings should respect them (at least for all the latin sets)

Answer (score 0):

For others visiting, this error also (expectedly) appears when using the jade API incorrectly.

per the docs

`var fn = jade.compile('string of jade', options);`

however, if you accidentally interpret this as

`var fn = jade.compile('/path/to/file.jade', options);`

you will have issue. :)